# Virtual Disk driver for Windows in user mode?

Tags: windows, driver, wdf

Is it possible to implement driver of Virtual Disk only in User mode or it has to be done in Kernel mode?

Comment: http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-help/82726-umdf-storport.html

Comment: @Hans Passant  In the link you provided Don refers to storport model. I'm interested if there any layer/space between Volume stack/FS stack (on upper level of io chain on one hand) and deeply located storport driver (on other hand) - so I can implement quite simple virtual disk driver just for learning purposes at this moment.